# Reputation probabilities

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Is there a probabilistic model for what one's reputation can be on MSE? I can of course obtain increments of points in +2, +5, + 10, + 15, +50, +100. Are there models for what my reputation will statistically have a higher likelihood of becoming?

Comment: Compound poisson process? Assuming there is no daily cap on reputation?